# download image from firebase storage in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, download, imageview, firebase-storage

Have the image location as gs://olio-ae400.appspot.com/Listings/Food/-M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi/MainImage

I want to download from this firebase storage location to imageview.
Have used below code,but the unable to download image from url?

```
 let storage = Storage.storage()
 var reference: StorageReference!
       
        reference = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://olio-ae400.appspot.com/Listings/Food/-M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi/MainImage")

 reference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
           print("image url is",url!)
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
            let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
            self.img.image = image

        }
```

Getting error at downloadURL line while retrieving the url for it in the response.

What is the correct way for it to download the image?

[image]

Comment: You should probably add an extension to your filename. Storage doesn't care about extensions so you can use any string as a filename but it will make things cleaner for you later when you want to access the file. So instead of `-M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi/MainImage")` initially store the file as  `-M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi/MainImage.jpg")`. Also, you're not downloading the file correctly. See [Download to a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file). And then note that .downloadUrl gets the download URL for an existing file

Comment: Have edited the question and added the location where the image is stored.You can see the file format is image/jpeg.

Comment: Very good. Now, review the documentation I linked in my above comment which shows the correct way to download an image from Storage. You can download it in memory using `.getData(maxSize:` or you can download it to disk using `.write(toFile:`. Go by what's in the documentation and let us know where you get stuck (update the code in your question if you do)

Comment: i shall try the code and update you

Comment: i used firebaseUi and it worked.the code is as follows:

Comment: let ref2 = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://hungry-aaf15.appspot.com/Listings/Food/-MV04bNvewyGPHMYUkK9/MainImage")

        cell.img.sd_setImage(with: ref2)

Comment: Great! If you came up with a solution that works, you can add it as an answer so it can help others! Code is hard to read in comments so adding it as an answer is best practice.

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

Install the pod firebaseUI.

import FirebaseUI

fetch the reference from the storage and set the reference to the imageview directly using SDwebimage as shown below.

```
let ref2 = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://hungry-aaf15.appspot.com/Listings/Food/-MV04bNvewyGPHMYUkK9/MainImage") 

cell.img.sd_setImage(with: ref2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify path and it's extension, then Use:

```
let path = "Listings/Food/-M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi/MainImage.jpg"
let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: path) 

reference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
        if let err = error {
           print(err)
      } else {
        if let image  = data {
             let myImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: image)

             // Use Image
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The image is inside the -M3g8pZDGmApicUAQtOi folder.giving it with extension jpg is showing 404 error.

Comment: can you post your storage rules? @saranya

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: It's not the rules - the filename was intially stored without the .jpg extension.

Comment: Then how to do download the image?

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5.6 and Xcode 13.4**

I opened name "Images" folder in Firebase and uploaded my image which name "Corleone" in jpg format.

Firstly I fetch image data then assigned to imageView. Lastly, i downloaded image URL. You can use two method differently.

You can copy all what i wrote and past your project inside of viewDidload or buttonAction.

```
 let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("Images/Corleone.jpg")
    
    storage.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "errror")
        }else{
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.imageView.image = image
            
            storage.downloadURL { url, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
                }else {
                    print(url ?? "url") //https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/epeycompare.appspot.com/o/Images%2FCorleone.jpg?alt=media&token=04c6369d-8036-4aef-8052-bac21c89eeda

                }
            }
        }
    }
```